# Unable to download File in Multithreaded call C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{          
     var File = MyMethod(fileGuid, fileName);
return File;
}

public virtual ActionResult MyMethod(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{
    //Gets Download data 
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment"))
    //refers filelocation which the file
    return File( filelocation, contentType);/
}
```

I can not download file if the method call is placed in thread. I get the following error:

> {"Value does not fall within the expected range."} at Response.AppendHeader

Comment: Why is this method has the async signature?`public async Task Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)`

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do.  First, MyMethod is an Action Method, and should only be called by the framework (you should not be creating a thread to do this).  Second, Download is async, so there is no reason to create a new thread to do this.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use the AppendHeader method when using the File result, it will automatically add it (and if you use the 3 parameter version, you can include the filename).

Comment: Ok.I'm trying to create a seperate thread on button click (load)which opens new page with another button(download)  for downloading my file.There I'm not able to download File cause it is being called in Thread.I will remove Async and use Thread concept here

Comment: And now If I remove append header. with return FilePathResult I'm not getting the prompt for download

Comment: I will repeat.  You should not be creating threads to do this.  If you want to open a new page, then do that (you'll need to do this in JavaScript on the client) and have it call a different action method.  Threads make no sense for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Ok.But I have an issue here.I'm opening the new window in Javascript(window.open) and calling the Download method.When the download process is going on I'm not able to perform operation in first window until file gets finished downloading.So I'm trying to use Thread concept.Any other suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: You MUST return the FIleResult to the calling method.  The Download method must return an ActionResult, and you must return the File result from Download.   Creating a thread does nothing here.  You're essentially creating a thread and then returning right away.  The problem is not what you think it is.  Download should contain nothing but the File() method, and it should return an ActionResult.

Comment: More than likely, your problem is in your javascript for opening a new method. You're probably opening a modal window, please specify the code you're using to create your new window.

Comment: By the way, this is what's known as an XY problem.  That's where you need to do X, and you think Y will solve your problem, but you can't figure out how to do Y, so you ask about Y when you really should be asking about X.  In this case, you need to download a file in a separate window, you should be asking how to do that.

Comment: $('#btndownload').on('click', function (e) { var url = "/Export/Download?dataSource=" + exportDS window.open(url, '_blank'); }

Comment: That should work, and absolutely should not interfere with the other window.  Again, creating threads is not going to work.  You have to understand the Request/Response pipeline of a web application.  If you create a new thread and return, it returns nothing.  The response ends before anything can be sent.  It's just never going to work.

Comment: OK.Erik I have changed the code above and tried.But I Still see it's blocking the UI of the first window.Not able to perform operations on first window until the file gets downloaded.